# How to analyze GC content of fasta file?

Tags: fasta, genome

I have the assembly file of a certain lizard species, I wanted to recreate Fig. 2 of the following paper, which compares the GC content distribution over 5kb windows, how would I go about doing this?

https://bmcecolevol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12862-022-02086-7#Sec10

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `bedtools makewindows` and `bedtools nuc` to compute the GC content for genomic windows as shown in Fig 2 of the linked paper.

See related question [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/9522847/).

This will slice the genome into 5Kbp (or whatever size specified to `makewindows`) pieces and compute the GC content of each piece, which can be plotted as a distribution as in the figure.

Something like this would work for the 5000 bp example:

```
# assemble a bedtools compatible genome file:
# see https://www.biostars.org/p/70795/ for hints how to do this.
bedtools makewindows -w 5000 -g my_genome.genome > windows.bed # you just made this .genome file manually
bedtools nuc -bed windows.bed -fi my_genome.fasta > windows_gc.bed
```

The bed output file will contain the GC content of each window in the `7_pct_gc` column (according to my understanding of the output file).

Comment: Please note that you do not have to make ".genome" file manually if you have `samtools`. You could simply generate an index file by running `samtools faidx genome.fasta`, and use the output file with extension `.fasta.fai` as input in your makewindwos command.

Comment: `tail -n +2 windows_gc.bed | cut -f 5 | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1*100)}' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'| sed 's/ /,/'>output.csv`. This should print a CSV file which you can easily plot.